# Using training data in my test query ? Seems wrong. What rules am I breaking?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions

Training a system to recognize Wikipedia topics in a sentence. Didn't divide the data into training set and test set, just used everything for training, including my test sentences.

The objective is to extract a representation of the sentence that I can simplify, so the purpose is to find Wikipedia topics, then substitute simpler terms. e.g. "Truck" instead of "Ford_Truck". or "Apple" instead of "Red_Apple".

Get hits on Wikipedia topics when testing using those test sentences. No surprize.

What is wrong with this picture ? A little concerned that I have skewed the test results by including my test sentences with training.

I don't quite have the chops to evaluate this approach, but intuition tells me I have just created a 1:1 lookup, which could have been done as easily with a lookup table. Why am I bothered by this ? Supervisor suggested it. Seems wrong. Yes, my intuition could be wrong. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: You really need to provide more details for anyone to be able to answer this. What technique did you use? What do you mean by "get hits on every topic"? What is your goal?

Comment: THanks. Your actual task still isn't clear. You're using some method to extract a sentence's representation. You're then doing something with these results to simplify them to the point you can do a Wikipedia lookup. Your "test sentences" are generated how? Can you not make some more to use? If you're testing the mechanism of turning a sentence into parts and simplifying parts and querying Wikipedia, I don't see any problem. So you must be talking about some of the technique you've left out that you think will not work on non-test data.

Comment: The concern is about the re-use of training data for test purposes. I think you have answered the question. Yes, I can make more. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a general answer. Training data provides the raw material from which a predictive model is generated. Testing using a sample which was used for training confirms that the predictive model has incorporated that training sample. This might be a step in the model validation process. Training and test data are usually kept separate (at least to begin with) to assess the predictive value of the model using unknown (new) data.

Comment: +1. The bottom line is: what question are you asking of your model? If you're asking, "How are you doing?" then testing on training data is okay. If you're asking, "How might you do in the future, on other data that comes in?" hold-out test data, cross-validation, etc, are needed. If "How might you do in the future, compared to competing models?" you need nested CV or other techniques.